# Using AND and bracket grouping in SQL not working

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I am trying to combine two conditions in a query but it isn't working. but running the conditions independently works.

LEt me explain. When I run this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*
FROM
    wp_users
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
WHERE
    (wp_users.user_login LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.user_email LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.user_url LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.display_name LIKE '%little%'
        OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
            AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%little%')
        OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
            AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%little%'))
ORDER BY
    user_registered DESC
```

I get this result

[image]

And when I run this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*
FROM
    wp_users
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
WHERE ((wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'car_type'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%Camry%')
    OR(wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'car_type'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%Toyota%'))
ORDER BY
    user_registered DESC
```

I get this result

[image]

As you can see, the user with ID 46 is common in both query result.

I only want to show users that matches both query conditions. In this case, user ID 46 only.

When I then combined them like so, I get nothing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*
FROM
    wp_users
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id)
WHERE
    (wp_users.user_login LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.user_email LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.user_url LIKE '%little%'
        OR wp_users.display_name LIKE '%little%'
        OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
            AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%little%')
        OR (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name'
            AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%little%'))
            
AND((wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'car_type'
    AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%Camry%')
    OR(wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'car_type'
        AND wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%Toyota%'))
ORDER BY
    user_registered DESC
```

[image]

This has been driving me nuts for hours now. Please help me figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @forpas My bad. Removed the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that if you used

```
SELECT wp_users.*, wp_usermeta.*
```

instead of just:

```
SELECT wp_users.*
```

you would see that the 2 queries that you try to combine, although they seem to return a common row, actually they don't.

By restricting the columns of the rows to only the columns of one of the tables you can't see that the other columns (of the other table of the join) are different.

Use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.*
FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m 
ON u.ID = m.user_id
WHERE 
  (
      u.user_login LIKE '%little%'
   OR u.user_email LIKE '%little%'
   OR u.user_url LIKE '%little%'
   OR u.display_name LIKE '%little%'
   OR (m.meta_key = 'first_name' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%little%')
   OR (m.meta_key = 'last_name' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%little%')
  )
  AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM wp_usermeta m 
    WHERE u.ID = m.user_id
      AND ( 
              (m.meta_key = 'car_type' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%Camry%')
           OR (m.meta_key = 'car_type' AND m.meta_value LIKE '%Toyota%')
          )
  )
ORDER BY u.user_registered DESC
```

Comment: I ended up using your solution even though the other solution by Gordon works too.

Answer (score 0):

You want *users* that match two conditions in the metadata.  I think of these queries as aggregating the metadata because values need to be combined from different rows.  And then those results are combined with the users table:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS u.*
FROM wp_users u INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MAX((um.meta_key = 'first_name' AND um.meta_value LIKE '%little%') OR
                 (um.meta_key = 'last_name' AND um.meta_value LIKE '%little%')
                ) as name_condition,
             MAX(((um.meta_key = 'car_type' AND um.meta_value REGEXP 'Camry|Toyota')) as car_condition    
      FROM wp_usermeta um
      WHERE um.meta_key IN ('first_name', 'last_name', 'car_type')
      GROUP BY um.user_id
     ) um
     ON u.ID = um.user_id
WHERE (u.user_login LIKE '%little%' OR
       u.user_email LIKE '%little%' OR
       u.user_url LIKE '%little%' OR
       u.display_name LIKE '%little%' OR
       um.name_condition
      ) AND
      um.car_condition
ORDER BY u.user_registered DESC;
```

Note other changes to the query:

- `SELECT DISTINCT` is not needed.  This adds overhead to the query.
- It uses a regular expression for the "Toyota"/"Camry" comparison.
- The conditions are calculated in the subquery and then. used in the outer query.